# Implementing zooming in CALayer

Tags: calayer, zooming, nsscrollview

I'm trying to implement zoom on a CALayer in a layered-hosting NSVIew. The NSView with the layer (size of the layer: 1024x768) is inside an NSScrollView. What I did to implement the zoom is the following

```
- (IBAction)zoomOut:(NSButton *)sender {
CALayer *layer = self.editorView.layer;
CGRect frame = layer.frame;
frame.size.width = frame.size.width / 2;
frame.size.height = frame.size.height / 2; 
layer.frame = frame;
}

- (IBAction)zoomIn:(NSButton *)sender {
   CALayer *layer = self.editorView.layer;
   CGRect frame = layer.frame;
  frame.size.width = frame.size.width * 2;
  frame.size.height = frame.size.height * 2; 
  layer.frame = frame;
}
```

After clicking on the button for zooming in or zooming out in the NSView, the problem is that whenever i scroll the NSView (remember that I put the NSView inside an NSScrollView, and that the NSView is bigger than the NSScrollView), the CALayer resizes automatically to the original size (i.e. 1024x768). I cannot figure out the reason.
Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`+ (CALayer *)layer` alias backing store (I call it root layer) resizes with the view, there is no way to prevent this.